# Deactivate Special Character Conversion with quotation marks

Tags: babel, csquotes, shorthands

Having this in TeX:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
"Error"\\
"Server"
\end{document}
```

compiles to

Ërror"
SServer"

I need to be able to use the `"` ASCII sign in the text of a latex document. I cannot use any kind of macro.

> Specific: I want to terminate the babel shorthand command, that is converting the `"` sign to an Ë

Expected Result:

"Error"
"Server"

EDIT:
Clarified ngerman and Goal

EDIT2:
clarified usage of the `"` sign

Comment: Do you happen to load the `babel` package? If so, with which language option? Please also clarify what "Tried csquotes, but no luck" might entail. E.g., did you try to employ the package's `\enquote`  macro? If so, with which options did you load the `csquotes` package?

Comment: My editor won't allow me to enter " at all It used to automatically generate `` and ''. Now it converts them to "` and "'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(updated the answer after learning that the OP wants to disable `babel` shorthands)

You need to change

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

to

```
\usepackage[shorthands=off,ngerman]{babel}
```

in order to diasble babel shorthands.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to deactivate this behaviour?
I am templating the document content and cannot control what is coming in, so the " sign must be possible without conversion.

Comment: @flymg - Please clarify what you mean by "deactivate this behavior". E.g., do you wish to terminate all babel shorthand commands? Or just some of the shorthands? Please be specific. Is something stopping you from writing `"{}Error"` and `"{}Server"`? Incidentally, why do you apparently insist on using dumb quotation marks?

Comment: I need to be able to use the " ASCII sign in the text of a latex document. I cannot use any kind of macro. I updated the question.
I want to terminate the babel shorthand command, that is converting the " sign to an Ë

Comment: @flymg - Please see my updated answer.

Comment: perfect, thank you